# CSS в разные браузеры

Tags: browsers, html, css

Как правильно для всех 5 браузеров записывается условие в html файле? То есть если ie, то один css, если safari то другой и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в html файле можно прописывать условные комментарии только для ие, все остальные браузеры проигнорируют запись, а вот в цсс можно использовать -webkit (хром и сафари), -moz(firefox), -o (opera), -ms (ie)

```
body{
padding:10px;
-moz-padding:8px;
-webkit-padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. CSS для разных браузеров пишется в одном css и тогда надо использовать css-хаки. Для этого можно воспользоваться ресурсом http://browserhacks.com/ , где показано что и для какого браузера надо писать.
2. Если хочется сделать так, чтобы для каждого браузера был свой файл, например, styles-ie.css или styles-moz.css или styles-safari.css и т.д.

Тут придется использовать php. В сети есть уже готовые решения, например это https://artisansweb.net/detect-browser-php-javascript/